# DDD - Entity creation and validation responsibility

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

I'm interested in DDD (Domain Driven Design) in the last days, but I can't figure out the responsibilities of who creates and validates the entities. Ill break this questions to cover different scenarios.

1. Regular entity (Possibly with value object). As an example lets take a user who is identified by Email. I have a UserFactory that receives an array of data (possibly from form POST), and return me a new UserEntity. Should the factory validate the integrity of the data (ex: string given as Email is a real email, passwords in password field 1 and field2 match and etc)? Should the factory validate that no such user exists already (we dont want to register two users with the same email)? If yes should it do it my itself or using the UserRepository?
2. Aggregate entity. Lets assume we have a Post entity and Comments entities. I want to get post 12 with all its comments, so I do something like

   $post = $postRepository->getById(12);

How getById should be implemented? like this:

```
public function getById($id) {
    $postData = $this->magicFetchFromDB($id);
    $comments = (new CommentRepository())->getForPost(12);
    return new PostEntity($postData, $comments);
}
```

Or maybe the post responsible for lazy creating its comments, something like:

```
class PostEntity {
    public function getComments() {
        if(is_null($this->_comments)) $this->_comments = (new CommentRepository())->getForPost($this->_id);
        return $this->_comments;
    }
}
```

?
I'm very lost here and there is not enough information with examples for DDD in PHP, so any help will be appreciated!

Thank you a lot,
skwee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The factory should *only* care about creating entities. I personally preferr to put validation both in my views and in the model layer. I'd use some library like jQuery's validation plugin to make some **essential** validation on the client side (like checking if required fields have data). And then do the "hardcore" validation on the model.
     I do this is by using a simple BaseEntity abstract class which all entities extend, and since you asked for an example, here it is:

  ```
  abstract class BaseEntity {
      public function isValid();
  }         

  class MyEntity extends BaseEntity {
       public function isValid() {
           //actual validation goes here
       }
   }
  ```

  You could also make use of a static helper class with some basic validation methods:

  ```
  class ValidationHelper {
      public static function isValidPhonenumber($value) {
          //check valid phonenumber, using a regex maybe
      }

      public static function isAlphanumeric($value) {
          //check for letters and numbers only
      }
  }
  ```

  Many argue against static methods because they can break unit tests, but in this case they are pretty basic and they don't have external dependencies, thus making them "safer".
- When it comes to checking for already existing entities you can do this by querying your DB to see if the entity is already there before adding/updating, or (this is how I like to do it) you could add a `unique` index to those columns that can't be repeated in the DB, and then wrap the create or update queries in a try-catch block (the query will throw a unique constraint violation, if two users have same e-mail for example) and then show the proper error message
- On your last question it comes down to a matter of preference. If your DB will get a million hits in 1 minute, then it's probably better to use lazy loading to avoid fetching unnecesary data until it's needed. But if your database is relatively small you could perfectly use eager loading without sacrificing too much performance.
  Again, this is a matter of personal preference.

hope some of this rambling makes sense, cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your comment! A) I'm not sure about putting validation in the entity. Would you consider validating captcha be part of the business logic? And what if I have admin panel to manually add users without the need of captcha? B) Yes I can, but the question is whose responsibility it is? Validation layer? Factory? Repository? C) Ok but what if I have User who have posts that have comments, will it be smart to load all this data to display the user profile page?

Comment: a) it depends on your needs really, i have found it "easier" to have validation in the entity itself using helper classes. but adding an extra layer of validation is perfectly fine. b) i would say it's the validation's layer responsibility. if two Accounts can't have the same number and you try to add one with a number that already exists, that means that entity is **invalid**, or at least thats what i think.

Comment: c) this also depends on what you want. if you are going to show all that info at once on the profile page then yes, load all the info in one call. but if you show, lets say, only the posts, and when you click on one you show the comments, it would be better to load the comments in that moment, maybe using ajax

Comment: b) well, then factory is just a glue layer between validating the data (via different layer, validation) and returning a valid entity (or error in case if the entity is invalid). c) its a bit complex, for the example lets assume I want to display only user details and load posts on demand (ajax), then User entity needs to know about PostRepository, and this ties the code together (which IMHO is bad). Maybe I should look into Observer pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest way for this is to use Doctrine2. Maybe the first hours will be hard, but once you master the Doctrine2 all such relationships and aggregate are piece of cake.

You can find plenty of information about PHP & DDD or Doctrine2 on http://giorgiosironi.blogspot.com/ or just by googling.

RE: Validation - considering the Single Responsibility Principle we use Validation objects. Validation can be complex and may require other repositories or entities so it is better to keep it apart from the actual entity - subject of the validation to avoid creation of bloated objects. You can either use visitor or specification design pattern.

There is plenty other posts here regarding those topics - try to use the above keywords.

Comment: I used doctrine back then, didn't really liked it, it was big and heavy. However it was pre Doctrine2, I might give Doctrine a shot again. However I'm still more interested in the proper way of doing things than finding a ready solution. As for validation, thanks for bringing the SRP! I forgot about it at all and was not sure if I should insert another layer of Validation, now I'm sure I need :)

Comment: Doctrine was based on Active Record pattern, Doctrine2 is exactly what you need for easier implementation of DDD. As I wrote on another similar post - home-built solutions usually end up as maintenance nightmare and Aggregate Roots become very manual. Usually every AR is done different way based which developer made it. Been there, trust me, you don't want to go that way ...

Comment: I have "reinvent-the-wheel" syndrome. If I were asked to implement DDD at my work place with tight schedule I'd probably go with Doctrine. Since my question was raised from my personal project, in which I don't have strict dead lines, I prefer to learn as much as possible by implementing this stuff. I have a nice solution ATM but I'm afraid it will break as soon as Ill try to complicate it, so I'm considering Doctrine. Also AFAIK Doctrine does not support non DB storage (i.e. file based or noSQL databases), this might be an issue for the future (I'm sure writing a driver is not a problem).

Comment: I am using Doctrine in my research project with MongoDB and I think there is a CouchDB driver as well - https://github.com/doctrine/couchdb-odm